# Start AVD but not showing up

Tags: android, android-emulator, android-virtual-device

I'm learning Android rightnow and want to emulate my codes in AVD. the problem is when I started the AVD, it doesnt show up at all. This is the console messages.

> [2013-01-04 12:17:35 - SDK Manager] skin.dynamic=no
>   [2013-01-04 12:17:35 - SDK Manager] hw.keyboard=no
>   [2013-01-04 12:17:35 - SDK Manager] vm.heapSize=32
>   [2013-01-04 12:17:35 - SDK Manager] hw.ramSize=512

I also already waited for a couple of minutes, but still nothing showing up.
And these are the configuration of my AVD

> Device: NexusS One 
>   Target: API level 17 (my target SDK is 2.3.3)
>   CPU/ABI = ARM(armeabi-v7a)
>   memory options = RAM 512 VM heap 32
>   Internal Storage = 200 MiB
>   SD card = 200 MiB

I also checked the DDMS, but no emulator at all in the list of devices

can someone help me to troubleshoot this problem?

Thanks

Comment: you have to do some interaction with emulator as well as it has been started.

Comment: kill the process `AVD.exe` from `Task Manger`. And restart `eclipse`. If it not helps you..create a new `AVD` and try again...

Comment: 1) In your SDK Manager, check that the System Image has been installed 2) Try start your emulator from the AVD Manager 5) Wait 5 minutes

Comment: Thanks you for the answers. the System Image has been installed and I also restarted the eclipse, but the problem still unsolved even I waited more than 5 minutes. any idea?

Answer (score 3):

Solution for Arch Linux:

Emulator AVD uses own library `libstdc++`, but it is incompatible with Arch Linux. To fix this link system library:

```
$ cd <path/to/sdk>/emulator/lib64/libstdc++
$ mv libstdc++.so.6 libstdc++.so.6.bak
$ ln -s /usr/lib64/libstdc++.so.6
```

Worked for me.

Comment: Worked for me too (also Arch Linux).

Answer (score 1):

If the System Image is installed in your system and graphics drivers are installed, and till not working then might be you can try this out.

I am not sure if it will solve your problem, but this is the way to make android emulator blazing fast.

Now if your system have a Processor that have a feature called as Intel Virtualization Technology, then Intel X86 images will be huge benefit for you. because it supports  Intel® Hardware Accelerated Execution Manager (Intel® HAXM).

To check that your processor support HAXM or not : **[Click Here](http://ark.intel.com/Products/VirtualizationTechnology)**

You need to manually install the Intel HAXM in your system. Follow these steps for that.

- First of all go to -  adt -> extras -> intel -> Hardware_Accelerated_Execution_Manager
- Make sure that Intel Virtualization is enabled from BIOS Settings.
- Now install Intel HAXM in your system and select amount of memory(i prefer to set it as default value).
- After installation create new AVD which should have a Target of API Level xx
- Now set the CPU/ABI as Intel Atom(x86).
- If you are on Windows then do not set RAM value more than 768 MB while setting up an emulator.
- Run the emulator. It will be blazing fast then ordinary one.

Hope it will be helpful for you. :)

Answer (score 0):

AVD can try configure again, By looking with that processor work maybe it would be good to change the settings for AMR v7 and work, but creates a new one

Comment: check out this tutorial:   http://piedralibre.wordpress.com/2010/11/11/como-crear-un-avd-android-virtual-device/

Answer (score -1):

Try to disable the ADB under Tools/Android/EnableADBIntegration. Then enable it again. It may just need to refresh. Worked for me.

https://www.youtube.com/watch?v=OKdth9RmBgo